# PHP get how long is the user Login using Saved Session

Tags: php, session, cookies

Do someone know how to get the how long in hours and or minutes is the user login using an saved session on PHP?

This is how I get the saved session on cookie.

```
<?php
$_id = md5('pk');

if(isset($_COOKIE[$_id]) && !empty($_COOKIE[$_id])){
    setcookie($_id, $_COOKIE[$_id], time()+7200000, '/');
    header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    print(
            json_encode(
                        array(
                                $_id=>$_COOKIE[$_id]
                            )
                    )
        );
}
else{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 No active session");
}


?>
```

Comment: It's just that, a "session". A session is stored until the user closes their browser.

Answer (score 0):

What happen is I save the session to the cookies and I added an expire date which is 3 months. So whenever they close the browser the session will stay because it is save on the cookies.

So the users wont be able login and logout everyday if they want.
Whenever they open the site again they will dont have to login again but if depends if they clear their cookies or logout.

The thing is I want to get how many hours the users use the system even without login and logout.

Just using the session from the cookies and time will be saved to the Database.